# Overriding Accounts.onEmailVerificationLink

Tags: meteor

Whenever I have `Accounts.onEmailVerificationLink` in clent side startup function, I get the following error message:

`Accounts.onEmailVerificationLink was called more than once. Only one callback added will be executed.`

What should I do to override this function correctly?

Answer (score 0):

**Accounts.onEmailVerificationLink** should be called in top-level code, not inside Meteor.startup().

You can try this:

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {
    Accounts.onEmailVerificationLink(function(token, done) {
    ...
    });
}
```